# How to prevent an error to display to user

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I have a simple code for sending mails. sometime `$host` might not available or my `SMTP` server might be down but what happens in these cases `swiftmailer` throws lot of exceptions and `$result` despite of returning `true` or `false` give me a complete mess of errors.

so how i can turn off the errors for this page of code **but not for the whole library**?

```
    $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance(self::$host, 25)
    ->setUsername(self::$username)
    ->setPassword(self::$password);

    //Create the Mailer using your created Transport
    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance("Custom Sheets");
    $message->setFrom(array('EDB@abc.com.pk' => 'Approval of Custom Duty Sheet'));
    $message->setTo($to);
    $message->setBody($html,'text/html');
    //Send the message
    $result = $mailer->send($message);
```

Comment: Why would you *not* want to know when the SMTP server is down?

Comment: Infact this mail is being sent through ajax in json response and such errors effect the json format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch that exception and handle it:

```
try {
    $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance(self::$host, 25)
            ->setUsername(self::$username)
            ->setPassword(self::$password);

    //Create the Mailer using your created Transport
    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance("Custom Sheets");
    $message->setFrom(array('EDB@abc.com.pk' => 'Approval of Custom Duty Sheet'));
    $message->setTo($to);
    $message->setBody($html,'text/html');
    //Send the message
    $result = $mailer->send($message);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    // handle error here
}
```

Turning off errors / warnings / notices in general:

```
error_reporting(-1);
```

Comment: it is still throwing warnings. is there any way to turn off warnings

Comment: @MuhammadHaseebKhan I added a note to my answer.

Comment: i just needed to turn off the Warning which i did through `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);` but anyway thanks for your help